# Disable Drag and Drop feature in Open File Dialog

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I have implemented the drag and drop using dropzone.js and I used "**Browse**" link.

The **Browse** link is using the HTML file upload and my code is:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Browse</a>
<input id="upload" type="file" style="display:none;" />
```

On clicking the browse, it opens the "**Open**" file dialog box.

Now What I want to do is, I want to disable the "**Drag & Drop**" feature  for that dialog. That is, If I select and drag the files, files getting dragged in that dialog and displays like "**+Copy or +Move(Without releasing the mouse button)**". I want to disable this feature in that **Open** file dialog. I want to upload by clicking **Open** *button* only and not by ***dragging*** in that dialog box.

How to disable the drag feature for that dialog?

Comment: if you provide a jsfiddle replicating your problem you will get more responses

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to drag-drop file in input file up-loader, you can use

```
  $('#upload').on('drop', function (e) {
     return false;
});
```

Comment: i jus disabled the drag and drop feature for this ID "upload" It worked for me in both IE 11 and chrome. thanks naveen

Comment: I gave it like the following: <input id="upload" type="file" style="display:none;" ondrop="return false;" />@Naveen Ravichandran